# Varnish round robin with different req.http.host for different servers

Tags: varnish

I have a varnish4 setup with 2 backend www servers. I would like to load balance between them in rr fashion but setting the proper virtual host for the proper server.

```
sub vcl_init {
        new vdir = directors.round_robin();
        vdir.add_backend(www1);
        vdir.add_backend(www2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.http.host ~ "^(www\.)?site1\.company\.com$") {
                set req.http.host = "site1.webserver1.lan.company.com";
                set req.backend_hint = vdir.backend();
        } 
...
```

Now the problem here is that webserver2 expects req.http.host = "site1.webserver2.lan.company.com"; so when it gets to it's turn it will not function.

Anybody knows how to do this? It is not possible to set this in the direct server (www1, www2) declaration, you can only set heartbeat check parameters in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't, because which backend the director chooses isn't exposed to you at any stage, with any of the default directors.

Why are you rewriting the host headers anyway, surely you can configure your backend servers to serve for 'www.)?site1.company.com', they don't need to care if they get traffic for their particular backend hostname 'site1.webserver1.lan.company.com', they just care about the site1.company.com name?